# Two different observable on same Firestore collection causing memory leaks and showing duplicate results

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I'm using @angular/fire to fetch data from firestore. I have two components. one is parent and the other is child. Both of these components are subscribing to observable using async pipes. These are two different observables (but on the same collection). When i arrive on the child route i can see the data from parent route is there until the child component's observable gives response and replaces the data that shouldn't be there. Why is this happening?

This is the method that returns an observable which is used the parent component.

```
getMyTasks(workspaceID, userID) {
return this.afs.collection('Tasks', ref => ref.where(`workspaceID`, '==', workspaceID).where(`members.${userID}`, '==', true))
  .snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Task;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      let member = data.members;
      let isMember = false;
      for (var b in Object.keys(data.members)) {
        if (Object.keys(member)[b] === userID) {
          isMember = true;
          break;
        } else {
          isMember = false;
        }
      }

      let createdBy = data.createdBy;
      let creatorName = "";

      for (let i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
        if (this.members[i].memberId === createdBy) {
          creatorName = this.members[i].data.name;
        }
      }
      return { id, creatorName, isMember, ...data };
    }))
  );
```

}

```
this.tasks$ = this.firestoreService.getMyTasks(this.workspaceID, this.userID);
```

And then i'm using async pipe in the template.
And here is the method which is used in child component

```
getTasks(projectId, members) {
return this.afs.collection('Tasks', ref => ref.where('projectId', '==', projectId).orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))
  .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Task;
    const docId = a.payload.doc.id;
    let createdBy = data.createdBy;
    let creatorName = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
      if (members[i].memberId === createdBy) {
        creatorName = members[i].data.name;
      }
    }

    return { docId, ...data, creatorName }
  })))}
```

this is child component.ts

```
this.tasks = this.firestoreService.getTasks(this.projectId, this.members);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `CollectionReference` is an object which exists only once per collection.

So if you do another query to this collection the first query is overwritten but the subscription stays active.

The parent and the child listen both for the same query hence the duplicate results.

I see three solutions to solve this problem.

1. The parent should just get the data once and the child could listen
   to data changes.
2. If the child is showing Tasks which are belonging to the parent
   Task. You should create a collection for these Sub-Tasks and query
   this collection.
3. If you do not need the data updated on changes you could just get
       all the data once.

I depends on what you are trying to achieve.

**Edit:**

If all document have the same structure.

4. You could query all the documents you need. Maybe all documents which the user can access.

   Then you could create a service which subscribes to the query observable. Now you have to process the documents, filter or whatever. And create two new observable which emit your filtered documents.

   Every time the query observable emits an update, you could emit the newly updated data with your observables.

This way you just can use async pipe on your observables.

This is maybe the best solution if there is a connection between your parent and child `Tasks`.

Comment: No. This isn't the problem. I'm trying to map each individual document. That's how it is done in AngularFirestoreCollection. If i remove the map like you did. I need to perform a loop to get the data of each returned document.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your code. You use map on the DocumentSnapshot array. I was not used to map i normally use forEach. My bad.

Comment: I have a new Idea on what could cause the problem. But i am no expert, i have edited my answer.

Comment: Well, i need to listen to changes on both components. And unfortunately i can't change the collection structure or make new one as they are being used in other applications as well. Guess i need to try different things to work it out.

Comment: Then i would mirror the data in a second collection. I do not know your situation but the easiest way would be to change the code in the other app so they create a copy of the data in a second collection. But if you can not change it there you could use a Cloud Function which listens to changes in the collection and updates the documents in the second collection.

Comment: i appreciate your help. I would definitely try it out. But i still don't get it why would the two different observables get merged. I understand that the collection is same. But queries are different. Even observables are different

Comment: In my opinion your data is not modeled as intended for Firestore. You should not have different kinds of documents in the same collection. If you have some influence on the other app you should change how your data is structured.

Comment: The structure of all documents in the collection is similar. The real issue is with my code structure. There must be something that is interconnecting them. Is there anything to do with interface on which i am mapping i tried to use different interfaces for each observable but it didn't work.

Comment: If the documents are all the same structure. Do they have a connection? Do you want to load just document which the user has access to?

Comment: Added an additional solution to my answer :)